# How do I manage Visual Studio file dependencies without editing the project file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Whenever we want to make files in Visual Studio depend on another file, we have to edit the `.csproj` file and place the file in a `<DependentUpon>` element. Is there an extension or hidden feature that allows this to be done from within Visual Studio without editing the project file and reloading the project?

Comment: If you vote down, please be kind enough to explain why. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Looking for the same thing but now with .NET Core

Comment: Nope @Kim seems to be still an issue we face even in VS2019 I've not seen a method to drag and drop one file onto another to define a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You *have* to edit the `.csproj` file to set up the dependency.

If you do this from within Visual Studio this will cause the project to be reloaded.

If you want to avoid reloads then you *could* edit the file outside Visual Studio (it's just xml) and then load it, but you would have to get the syntax correct. It's far simpler to let Visual Studio do its thing.